Should a Java project use UTF-16?
Java, by default, uses UTF-16 to represent characters in the String data type.
I inherited a JavaFX project which currently has some Strings in UTF-8 and others in UTF-16. This is causing bugs (in pop-ups for example) and I'm at a stage where I must provide some uniformity and choose between one and the other. Do note that for the pop-ups, I must use UTF-8 because UTF-16 doesn't show the characters correctly (I'm not sure why this happens, nor is that the focus of this question).
If Java used UTF-8 by default, I would absolutely use it as well because it is the de facto encoding for the foreseeable future. However, since Java uses UTF-16 by default, I was thinking of changing everything to UTF-16 to be consistent with the language, and then if need be when creating these pop-ups convert to UTF-8. Since there are many pitfalls associated with this encoding, of which a good summary is [1], I'm scared that I'm making the wrong decision.
So, which encoding should I use to store my String variables?
A similar question [2] was asked but for PHP and not between UTF-16 and UTF-8. I believe this qualifies as a different question due to Java natively using UTF-16.
[1] - Should UTF-16 be considered harmful?
[2] - Should I convert the whole project to UTF-8?

Java strings are inherently UTF-16. It is not something you have control over. But when reading and writing files you might use utf-8 encoding for the files, and it would be a good idea to consistently use UTF-8.

@JacquesB I do use UTF-8 for the files, if you mean the source code files. What I am talking about are the Strings I use in the application. Even though Java strings are inherently UTF-16, you can create UTF-8 strings with the String constructor.

So I'm talking about having those strings, some of them which I also have stored in an XML file, encoded in UTF-8, or UTF-16. UTF-16 is the easiest option, since Java uses it by default. The other option is converting all the Strings I create to UTF-8 on creation, which seems more cumbersome (even though, as I mention in the question, I will have to convert some of them anyway)

This sounds like you're suffering mojibake/double-encoding issues. Fix those. It is not meaningful to talk about the encoding of a String, because conceptually Strings are sequences of already-decoded chars (which correspond to Surrogate Halves, not Unicode Codepoints/Scalars). Java code cannot determine or control how those Strings are actually represented in memory (but having read the OpenJDK source code, I know that Strings may be represented as Latin-1 or UTF-16 depending on contents).

@chilliefiber Are you talking about the constructors which take a byte array and a charset parameter? In this case the encoding applies to the input byte array, not the resulting string.

The internal representation of characters inside the Java virtual machine is not relevant to how you choose to store your text strings outside of it.  The world is moving towards UTF-8 (since ASCII strings are valid UTF-8 too).  Go with that.

@JacquesB yes I am talking about those constructors. If you do something like String s = new String("çàáõ".getBytes(), "UTF-8"); alert(s); the code for the pop-ups works, and if not it doesn't work with those characters: if I do alert("çàáõ") I get the mojibake @amon talked about . So, I have to make sure all the strings, be they strings from exception messages, strings stored in the XML or other strings were created equal when I want to create a pop-up

I'm sorry to everyone but I just realised my question was made under false assumptions. I saw that conversion to UTF-8 being done in the code and assumed it was a problem because the XML was stored in UTF-8 and so were the source files but Java uses UTF-16. In reality the javac command was being issued with a third encoding (don't ask me why) and that was the root of the issues

There are some basic misunderstandings at play here, which you may want to spend some time ironing out.

Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful

Java uses UTF-16 internally. But nobody needs to care about that, except for a tiny bit of efficiency.
UTF-8 is much more what everyone uses as the standard for external representation.
